# a view containing UITableView and UITabBar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I am using UINavigationController to push and pop other UIViewControllers in my app.
In one of the UIViewControllers I am using UITabBar to switch between different views. One of the view has UITableView and I am having difficulty showing the tabBar at the bottom. Even if it shows up it scrolls up and down with the tableCells.
I didn't use the tabbarcontroller because apple documentation recommends not to push tabbarcontroller on to navigationcontroller stack.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using UITableViewController. The View of the UITableViewController is the tableView itself, so when you add the tab bar to the view you actually add it to the table view. that is why it scrolls with it.

you should create a regular UIView, and then add the tableView and the tab bar to that view.

shani